# OpenLayers VectorLayer from GeoServer wont show up

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, vector-layer

I have a SQLServer database containing geospatial data, have created layers from those data in GEOServer and it works fine, I'm working on a webgis application to allow users select features on the map, so I needed a vector layer and I created one, problem is it won't show up. I tried setting projection and style but it didn't make any difference. Hear is the code:

(Note: Blocks layer which is TileLayer version of the same source works fine, and the ajax actually returns data, but there is no layer on the map
[image]
)

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
        .map {
            height: 400px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <div>
        <span id="status">&nbsp;0 selected features</span>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and javascript:

```
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import {click, pointerMove, altKeyOnly} from 'ol/events/condition.js';
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON.js';
import Select from 'ol/interaction/Select.js';
import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer.js';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector.js';

var layerWFS = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        loader: function(extent) {
            $.ajax('http://192.168.1.55:7001/geoserver/TR_SQL/ows', {
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                    service: 'WFS',
                    version: '1.1.0',
                    request: 'GetFeature',
                    typename: 'TR_SQL:GIS_Blocks_Linear',
                    outputFormat: 'application/json'
                }
            }).done(function(response) {
                layerWFS
                .getSource()
                .addFeatures(new ol.format.WFS()
                  .readFeatures(response));
            });
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
        projection: "EPSG:4326"
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 3
        })
    })
});

var Blocks = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://192.168.1.55:7001/geoserver/TR_SQL/wms',
        params: { 'LAYERS': 'TR_SQL:GIS_Blocks_Linear', 'VERSION': '1.1.1' },
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        projection: 'EPSG:4326'
    })
});

var Stations = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://192.168.1.55:7001/geoserver/TR_SQL/wms',
        params: { 'LAYERS': 'TR_SQL:Stations', 'VERSION': '1.1.1' },
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        projection: 'EPSG:4326'
    })
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM(),
          projection: 'EPSG:4326'
      }),
      layerWFS,
      Stations
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([55, 32]),
        zoom: 5
    })
});

var select = new Select({
    condition: click
});

var changeInteraction = function() {
    if (select !== null) {
        map.addInteraction(select);
        select.on('select', function(e) {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = '&nbsp;' +
                e.target.getFeatures().getLength() +
                ' selected features (last operation selected ' + e.selected.length +
                ' and deselected ' + e.deselected.length + ' features)';
        });
    }
};


/**
 * onchange callback on the select element.
 */
changeInteraction();
```

Comment: can you add one of the features that is being returned? most likely issue is that the axis are swapped.

Comment: @IanTurton do you mean to send a picture of generated map?

Comment: no, one of the elements in the response array

Comment: @IanTurton I updated the question, the second image shows the first element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are requesting `outputFormat: 'application/json'` and the output looks like a geojson so I think you need to read it using `ol.format.GeoJSON`.

Also you have `strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox` but are not passing bbox in the data, so it should either be `strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all` or you would need to set bbox in the data (extent transformed to 'EPSG:4326' and the coordinates supplied in Lat/Lon format).

If you are happy to load all (if only 429 simple features?) the following would be much simpler, OpenLayers will automatically load the url and read the data

```
source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'http://192.168.1.55:7001/geoserver/TR_SQL/ows' +
                    '?service=WFS' +
                    '&version=1.1.0 +
                    '&request=GetFeature' +
                    '&typename=TR_SQL:GIS_Blocks_Linear' +
                    '&outputFormat=application/json',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    }),
```